# iPhone 6 upgrade, restore missing photos?

Tags: upgrade, photos, ios, iphone

I just upgrade to my iPhone 6. I first made backup (to iCloud) on my iPhone 5, then i restored it on the iPhone 6. Now all works well and everything is there, **except all** my photos.

Anybody has a handy tip to restore **all** my photos from my iPhone 5?

Comment: Yes i did, there is only last month. All the previous months (and years) are not there. Its almost like it didn't full restored...

Comment: maybe have a look at http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4605

Comment: Was your iPhone set to sync photos with iPhoto. In that case I believe it gets excluded from the backup.